# How to make changes on the leaf node while not affecting the parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

All elements in the page are assigned to change background color and change border properties if hovered, but the problem is that the element I only want to change is the element directly under the cursor, It seems that when I hover something , all the parents of it is also hovered which is normal because you are also hovering to the parent of an element since its child is nested inside it.

But I found out that firefox screenshot feature can do this thing. It has a feature that lets you screenshot a certain part of the page, and in the selection process , It shows what part of the page is only saved by making a dashed border around it and a white overlay.

I think this has to do something with javascript but I don't know how to

1. Check if the element is hovered
2. Check if element is the one under the cursor by checking it's child if it's hovered.
3. Where to start checking things.

Let's say

```
<div>
    <div> put border on me if hovered </div>
    <div> put border on me if hovered 
        <span> put border on me if hovered and don't put border on parent </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
*:hover { border: 5px dashed white; }
```

I haven't made the javascript because I am stuck of what to do first

Comment: do you have code to show? what have you done?

Comment: The thing is that in what you're describing, _all those elements_ are under the cursor. A child element does not somehow invalidate a rectagular cut-out in its parent element. They're all hovered over. So what you want to figure out is how to write a CSS rule that says "if you're hovered, and your child is also hovered, _don't_ set a border"

Comment: I haven't made the javascript yet because I don't know where to start. Regarding to the css rule ,So how do I do that?

Comment: You also want to change your terminology: what you're describing is about the _leaf_ node, not the _root_ node. The "root" is the highest possible parent, you're talking about the most specific child instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want that when you hover over a specific element, its style has changed,I can offer to do this with the help of JS

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.setAttribute('style', 'border: 5px dashed red');
});

document.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
    e.target.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

You can change the style, in different ways, for example add a specific class. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So You want, when you hover on a particular div, that particular div must have border not the parent one.

So easy task can be achieved my CSS easily. you have to target the div's based on their className. 
( *Based on your code divs above* )

```
    <div>
      
      <div className="parentBorder"> put border on me if hovered </div>
      <div>
        <span> put border on me if hovered and don't put border on parent </span>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

### The CSS File for this

```
.parentBorder {
  border: none;
}
.parentBorder:hover {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

span {
  border: none;
}
span:hover {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

This will solve you problem
And by JAvaScript you can do this by initiating the onClick() Function event on the particular div for this task

Comment: That's a good trick but you're missing something, the div that has a span inside it has text : "put border on me if hovered" , and you're answer wouldn't put border on that div if the text is hovered.

Comment: NO, I'm answering that the border will be there when you hovered on a particular div.

As your question says that, You want to put border on that div which you hovered ? isn't ?

Comment: There will be a border when you hover on a particular div. If there is a problem comment me

Comment: Yes the border is in there but your answer is not applicable on much more deeper nested html elements.

Comment: As of your sample code this is fine, but if you have more nested elements in you react application target them through className, or make a separate class for hover just include that class in your desired element.